# List users with the same IP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query,

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_ip IN (SELECT user_ip FROM users GROUP BY user_ip having count(*) > 1)
ORDER BY user_ip
```

This works to list all users which has at least 1 repeated IP with another user.

I need to order all users by total of repeated IP.

ex. this users table

```
id, username, ip
1, user1, 1.1.1.1
2, user2, 2.2.2.2
3, user3, 1.1.1.1
4, user4, 4.4.4.4
5, user5, 2.2.2.2
6, user6, 2.2.2.2
```

should print,

```
ip, username, total
2.2.2.2, user2, 3
2.2.2.2, user5, 3
2.2.2.2, user6, 3
1.1.1.1, user1, 2
1.1.1.1, user3, 2
4.4.4.4, user4, 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach which uses an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT u1.ip, u1.username, u2.total
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ip, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM users
    GROUP BY ip
) u2
ON u1.ip = u2.ip
ORDER BY u2.total DESC
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3982/2)

Comment: oh, great. Never thought about doing a JOIN on the "same" table

Comment: This is called a "self-join" for obvious reasons.  You can add this to your SQL toolbox and use it when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip, username, count(*) total
FROM user_ip
WHERE ip in (
    SELECT ip
    FROM user_ip
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING count(*) > 1
)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3 DESC,1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT `t`.ip, `t`.username, COUNT(`t2`.`id`) total
FROM `test` `t`
LEFT JOIN `test` `t2` ON `t2`.`ip`=`t`.`ip`
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
ORDER BY COUNT(`t2`.`id`) DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5bb7/1/0